# Could not build Objective-C module 'Darwin' error for all packages

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Any time `swift build` is run from command line inside a package, it gives a manifest parse error.

```
/usr/local/include/stdbool.h:4:10: error: #include nested too deeply  
#include <stdbool.h>
         ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Darwin'
```

This error happens in any package I attempt to run it in, even new packages made with `swift package init`. I do not know if this includes packages made with Xcode because the same error occurs if I attempt to run `swift package generate-xcodeproj`.

Swift version:
`Apple Swift version 4.1 (swiftlang-902.0.48 clang-902.0.37.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0`

Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094495/swift-package-generate-xcodeproj-fails-with-swift-does-not-support-the-sdk) works for me