# `swift package generate-xcodeproj` fails with "Swift does not support the SDK"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm having trouble running `swift package generate-xcodeproj`. I created my package like this:

```
$ /Applications/Xcode9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift package init --type executable
```

(as I have many Xcode versions installed I explicitly targeted a `swift` binary when running the command so that I don't need to `xcode-select` all the time)

This created a `Package.swift` with the version header `// swift-tools-version:4.0`.

Now, when I run `swift package generate-xcodeproj` I get a fatal error:

```
$ /Applications/Xcode9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift package generate-xcodeproj
/Users/max.chuquimia/Desktop/xcode/MyPackage: error: manifest parse error(s):
<unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.12.sdk'
```

No `.xcodeproj` is generated. Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is the `$DEVELOPER_DIR` environment variable is wrong - it should also be made to point to the Xcode version that the `swift` binary resides in.

```
$ DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer /Applications/Xcode9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift package generate-xcodeproj
```